# Laravel workbench real-time chat

Tags: php, laravel, ember.js, real-time

I am followed up this guide 'https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-real-time-chat-eaa550829538', to create real-time chat in my app. All was alright, before "workbench" moment. I created "formativ/chat" workbench with composer, then created and fill files. After, i run "composer update" in

> 'workbench/formativ/chat'

directory and added

> 'Formativ\Chat\ChatServiceProvider'

to app.php. But then 'ember.js' just throw error in console

> 'can't establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:7778/.'

and nothing worked. Also if i'll write not-valide php code in

> workbench/formativ/chat/chat/command/Server.php

laravel will no throw any error

## Update

I finally got 'ServiceProvider' to work. But other files didn't work. I connected them to ServiceProvider with

```
$this->app->bind("chat.chat", function()
{
        return new Chat(
            $this->app->make("chat.emitter")
        );
});
```

In my workbench i have this architecture

> workbench_folder->vendor/appname/src/vendom/appname/

```
Command\Serve.php
Chat.php
ChatInterface.php
ChatServiceProvider.php
User.php
UserInterface.php
```

Comment: You haven’t given enough information. Is anything running at that address, for instance?

Comment: no, i already tried some different ports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just typed "php artisan chat:serve" and all works. Not found it in tutorial